# Function for recognizing type of input data

Tags: java, c

Is there any way to recognize whether my inputted data is an `int` or a `float` or a character?

I am supposed to do this particular task in C and Java programming language.

Suppose:

```
if(inputted date == int type)
   then do this.
else if(inputted date == char type)
   then do this.
```

?

Comment: There's a way of knowing if inputted data is in the form of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can discern some types by seeing if they can parse to the relevant type:

```
bool isFloat = float.TryParse(12.3);

bool isInt = int.TryParse(6);
```

The problem is that some numbers will parse both ways, so

```
bool isFloat = float.TryParse(6);
```

still works.  If you want this to read as an `int`, you can parse it as an `int` first, and then try `float` if `int` fails to parse.

Some languages, like Javascript, use one numeric type for all numbers, and this works just fine.  Divining the type of your input string may be less important than you think; in the majority of use cases, you probably already know the type before you even ask for the input.

Comment: i didn't get it clearly sir. and i think your ans is not relevant to my query i am searching for some thing easier like i demonstrated with an example in my question and also how to do this in c?